# Apache Reverse Proxy - HTTP requests with a Cookie

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, http-cookie, mod-balancer

We have an Apache Reverse Proxy which works fine (configuration below). Now we have the need to forward a few requests to another server (server3.domain.com) and check that a cookie named "LtpaToken" exists in user request. If the cookie is absent, the error page will return (we want to block anonymous requests).

I need to forward http(s)://server.domain.com/jsreports/* to JSReport's http(s) server VM ( server3.domain.com IP address) and check the LtpaToken if exists.

Can anybody give some hints how can it be implemented? Thank you!

```
        SSLEngine on
        SSLProxyEngine On
        SSLProxyVerify none
        SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerName off

ServerName server.domain.com
        ServerAlias server.com
        ProxyRequests Off
#   ProxyPreserveHost On
    
<Proxy balancer://my_cluster>
    BalancerMember https://server.domain.com keepalive=on
    BalancerMember https://server2.domain.com keepalive=on  status=+H
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    
#   ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
</Proxy>

 <Location /balancer-manager>
        SetHandler balancer-manager
        Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
        allow from 192.168.1
    allow from 5.5.20
    allow from 10.0.0
</Location>

    ProxyPass /balancer-manager !   
    ProxyPass / balancer://my_cluster/
    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://my_cluster/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the presence of the `LtpaToken=` string in the `Cookie` header, and serves the "/forbidden.html" page if it is not found.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond "%{HTTP:Cookie}" "!LtpaToken=" [NC]
RewriteRule ".*" "/forbidden.html" [R,P]
```

If you want to return a HTTP error (403), you can replace the last line with

```
RewriteRule ".*" - [F]
```

Comment: thank you very much. The above config will check for LtpaToken cookies in all the requests If I understand it correctly. Any possibility to check it only in the requests that have the /jsreports/* path?

Comment: These directives restrict the resource defined by the section they are located in. You can put these into a `<Location /jspreports>`, and then only paths beginning with `/jspreports` will require the presence of the cookie.